# (Ionic 5) Autenticação usando Json-Server

Tags: angular, ionic, login, autenticação

Bom dia, gostaria de uma orientação em realização um Login (Autenticação) usando Json-Server (FAKE API). O Json-Server suporta essa funcionalidade?

Estava seguindo umas aulas no Alura sobre Ionic e Angular, e eles usam o método POST para realizar o login do usuário, porém, ao tentar fazer isso no meu projeto usando Json-Server, ele adiciona os dados na API, sendo um login válido ou inválido!

Vou postar os meus códigos abaixo para tentar deixar claro os meus procedimentos.

O meu **Json-Server** no seu arquivo **db.json** contém os seguintes dados:

```
"usuarios": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "Dennis",
  "sobrenome": "Cezar",
  "endereco": "Endereço Completo",
  "telefone": "XXXXX-XXXX",
  "email": "dennis@gmail.com",
  "senha": "123",
  "acesso": 1
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "nome": "Marcos",
  "sobrenome": "Gonçalves",
  "endereco": "Endereço Completo",
  "telefone": "XXXXX-XXXX",
  "email": "marcos@gmail.com",
  "senha": "123",
  "acesso": 2
}
]
```

No meu componente **UsuarioService.TS** do Ionic está da seguinte forma:

```
API: string = "http://localhost:3000/usuarios/";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getLogin(email: string, senha: string) {
return this.http.post(this.API, {email: email, senha: senha});
}
```

No meu componente **LoginPage.HTML** está da seguinte forma:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">E-mail</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email" name="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <p *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').errors?.required" class="textoRequired">E-mail é obrigatório!</p>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" formControlName="senha" name="senha"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <p *ngIf="loginForm.get('senha').errors?.required" class="textoRequired">Senha é obrigatória!</p>
</ion-list>

<div>
    <ion-button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="ion-padding" expand="block" color="tertiary" (click)="loginUsuario()">Entrar</ion-button>
</div></form>
```

Finalmente, no meu componente **LoginPage.TS** está da seguinte forma:

```
 loginForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private router: Router,
             private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
             private usuarioService: UsuarioService,
             public toastController: ToastController) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     email: ['', Validators.required],
     senha: ['', Validators.required]
   });
 }

loginUsuario() {

const email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
const senha = this.loginForm.get('senha').value;

this.usuarioService.getLogin(email, senha)
                   .subscribe(() => {
                     console.log("Logou com sucesso!");
                   }, erro => {
                     console.log(erro);
                     this.loginForm.reset();
                   });
                   }
```

Espero que essas informações ajudem para esclarecer meus procedimentos.

O formulário pega os dados corretamente, só que em vez de verificar no Json-Server se o usuário existe ou não, ele faz a criação de um novo Objeto com os dados ID, Email e Senha que eu digitei nos campos de Login.

Será que o Json-Server não é preparado para isso, estou fazendo algo de forma incorreta?

Gostaria se possível de uma orientação!

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Então Dennis, provavelmente vc ainda não assistiu todas as aulas, o método **Post** irá criar novos usuários na Api e não autenticar, este trabalho de autenticação é totalmente a parte, trabalhoso e bem amplo. Talvez nas próximas aulas seja abordado o assunto ou não, não conheço o curso. Não sei te responder se com o `json-server` dá para realizar autenticação, o mais correto é perguntar na plataforma que está assistindo as aulas diretamente ao professor.

Comment: Obrigado LeAndrade!
Então, o curioso é que nas aulas o professor usa o método post para fazer a requisição de Login, por isso fiquei bem confuso. Eu fiz uma pergunta lá sobre isso e não souberam me informar.
Mas de qualquer forma, vou continuar pesquisando e tentando entender!
Obrigado!